# Odoo 10 : How to pass parameter to a tree view from button?

Tags: python, xml, button, module, odoo

I  added a button in contacts form like this :

```
<xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_button_box"]//button[@name="toggle_active"]' position='after'>   
                    <button type="action" name="%(survey.action_survey_user_input)d" string="Surveys" class="oe_stat_button"/>           
                </xpath>
```

[image]

which opens the below tree view of survey but without a filter on email id . how to pass email id with this button to the below tree view of survey??

[image]

**Info**: I tried to add context in the button tag but didnt work.

```
context="{'email': email}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it better using a button of type object and implement everything in python by returning the action dict with the required action domain to filter the records on the tree view or using a rec_id to open an specific record form

Answer (score 0):

this python function worked for me which is called by button (type : object)

```
@api.multi
def callSurvey(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    action_id = self.env.ref('survey.action_survey_user_input').read()[0]
    if action_id: 
        return {
            'name': action_id['name'],
            'type': action_id['type'],
            'res_model': action_id['res_model'], 
            'view_type': action_id['view_type'],
            'view_mode': action_id['view_mode'],
            'search_view_id': action_id['search_view_id'],
            'domain': [["email", "=", self.email]],
            'help': action_id['help'],
        }
```